# Custom Conventions in Entity Framework Database First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know that we can create custom conventions in EF Code first using this. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439.aspx

But is there any way I can apply same custom conventions in database first. I would like to apply a column renaming convention when I add new table to EF designer from the database.

Comment: did you get a solution to this question?
Thanks.

Comment: @ben Thanks for asking unfortunately no direct way. on code first i was told that i could modify the templates that are generated. Here. http://forums.asp.net/t/2070344.aspx?Custom+Conventions+in+Entity+Framework+Database+First but i think that is not convinent so for now i am doing things manually via code.

Comment: Me too. I ended up using code first.